# Table View Checkmark if Task Complete

Tags: objective-c, tableview, checkmark

I'm working in Objective C. I have a UITableViewController with about 25 cells that push to a UIViewController. When the user hits back, I want to see if the user entered the correct data for the given cell. (I have a working bool , we'll call it `isCellComplete` for now). If isCellComplete is true, I want to add a checkmark as the accessory to the cell. I've been trying to put the test in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but that method does not seem to run and refresh the cells everytime the view appears. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the `UITableView` method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. This is much more elegant than reloading the whole table view. And if you don't want an animation, you can specify `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` and it will look just like `reloadData` but be much more efficient.

You should do the check in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and if the check passes, set the cell's accessory to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. Then when you tell the table view to reload the appropriate row(s), it'll automatically call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on the data source and update that cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

And that will make `cellForRowAtIndexPath` be called again when the view appears